# How to make a conditional statement out of a string

Tags: php, string, variables, conditional-statements

Is this possible at all? The idea is to have the following:

```
if ($some_statement) { ... }
```

where $some_statement variable is a string, which looks like this:

```
$some_statement = ' $day == "Monday" && $weather == "sunny" ';
```

I have experimented a little with curly brackets and eval function, but could not get any to work. Thanks guys, you rock!

Comment: Where does the string come from, is it user input? Is it trusted user input?

Comment: many probably find it easier to write `if( $day == "Monday" && $weather == "sunny" )`

Comment: yes, user input should not be evaluated. Unless grate care is taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) for this, but keep in mind that the statement in the string must be a complete PHP statement.

```
$condition = 'return $day == "Monday" || $day == "Sunday";';
if (eval($condition)) { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this would not work without "return" and ";" at the end of a string!

Answer (score 2):

```
If (eval($some_statement)) {
```

should work.

**But don't do it** unless you know what you are doing, which judging by your question you don't.

Evaluating code in a string is very dangerous, and can very easily create serious security holes.

Comment: Thank you very much, and yes, you are right - I have no idea what I am doing :)